# Panda reading csv with a datetime column

Tags: pandas

I am trying to read a csv row like this:

```
headers = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4','col5','col6']
dtypes = {'col1': 'int', 'col2': 'str', 'col3': 'str', 'col4': 'str','col5': 'str','col6': 'int'}
test = pd.read_csv("solution.csv", sep=',', header=None, names=headers, dtype=dtypes, date_parser = pd.to_datetime)
```

if I now print out the values with test.values i get this array back:

```
array([[107, 'Berg Live', 'Berg', '2017-01-08','Concert', 7]], dtype=object)
```

However I need the "col4" as a datetime.date because I want to compare it to a sql query.
Is there an easy way(preferably while reading the csv) to do that?
I able to get it back as an Timestamp but that is useless for me because the sql query gives an datetime.date back.

Solution i am looking for should look like this:

```
array([[107, 'Berg Live', 'Berg',
        datetime.date(2017, 1, 8), 'Concert', 7]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: What if you use parse_dates = ['col4'] in the read_csv as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it locally at my end. If you want to read a column as datetime while reading the CSV itself, you can use [parse_dates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

So you can do:

```
df = pd.read_csv("solution.csv", sep=',', header = None, names = headers, dtype = dtypes, parse_dates = ['col4'])
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your Answer, however I just tried it and it gives me:
array([[107, 'Berg Live', 'Berg',
        Timestamp('2017-01-08 00:00:00'), 'Concert', 7]], dtype=object)
back. But what I need is datetime.date(2017, 1, 8), otherwise the compare statement
if((test.values[0] ==sql_statemtn.values[0]).all())
will always give false back.

Comment: I think you'll have to work with TimeStamp. It is the  Pandas replacement for datetime.datetime [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html). Underneath, it's type `numpy.datetime64` which I assume should be possible to make work with the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> col_names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']
>>> dtypes = {'col1': int, 'col2': str, 'col3': str, 'col5': str, 'col6': int}
>>> date_cols = ['col4']
>>> df = pd.read_csv('solution.csv', names=col_names, parse_dates=date_cols)
>>> df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 6 columns):
col1    1 non-null int64
col2    1 non-null object
col3    1 non-null object
col4    1 non-null datetime64[ns]
col5    1 non-null object
col6    1 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(2), object(3)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
None

>>> df.head()

    col1    col2        col3    col4        col5        col6
0   107     Berg Live   Berg    2017-01-08  Concert     7
```

You can operate on the TimeStamp object getting DateTime properties using the `dt` accessor.

```
>>> df['col4'].dt

<pandas.core.indexes.accessors.DatetimeProperties object at 0x114d02518>

>>> df['col4'].dt.day_name()

0    Sunday
Name: col4, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, while your solution would work it would be pretty inconvenience if I really want to compare the sql_statement with the df I would have to compare the fourth column separately like:
if((sql_statement["Datum"]==df['col4'].dt.date).all()):
       #code

Comment: For a list of supported `dtypes`, see [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#dtypes). Most straightforward is to stick to the officially supported types, even though it's  possible to define your own extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
test = pd.read_csv("solution.csv")    
test.to_datetime('col4')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if I just copy paste your statement I get an error:
"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'"

Comment: Sorry, my bad ---> test['col4'] =  pd.to_datetime(test['col4'])